# show password requirement bootstrap popover on hover/focus and pass explicit Html contents inside Popover to display

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, passwords, hover, popover

How can we show password requirements for a Password field using twitter Bootstrap pop-over and jquery on hover.

```
<input id = "txtPassword" type = "password"  title ="password" />
```

1. I want to pass custom "html" as the content of popover.
2. change title of pop-over to custom title
3. change the style of pop-over from current basic to custom style.

Answer (score 0):

for starter you can make things simple and use the simplest `popover` bootstrap:

1.include in your project the right files of bootstrap in order to make it work:
   a.`bootstrap-tooltip.js`
   b.`bootstrap-popover.js`
   c.`jquery.min.js`
   d.`bootstrap.css`

2.use an  element only as the element which will fire the `popover`, for example:

```
<a href="#" id="example" rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>
```

with the: `id="example"` you can access the  element with `jquery` in order to display a content with the `popover`

on the `data-content="some text"`: this is the text that will be shown on the `popover` window

on the `data-original-title="some title"`: you can decide what title to show on the `popover` window

3.use `jquery` to access and activate the `popover` like this:

```
$(function ()  
{ $("#example").popover();  
});
```

just start with that and then try to dig deeper to your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already have tried that and cannot get to display formatted Html.